# Неполная заливка svg элемента в Firefox

Tags: svg, firefox, path

Есть **`svg`**, внутри вставлен тег **`path`**, в котором нарисована картинка. В файле css имеется событие **`svg:hover`**. В нём меняется один цвет фона на другой. Но при наведение на элемент **`svg`** заливается не весь элемент,а поле под тег **`path`**, тогда как в **IE11** абсолютно весь (и **`svg`**, и **`path`**).

Подскажите пожайлуста в чем проблема.!

[Фотография проблемы](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ge966.jpg)

```html
<svg width="70" height="120">
<style>
    path{stroke:white;}
    svg{background:#0080FF;}
    svg:hover{background:#A9A9F5;}
    path:hover{fill:#FFFF00; stroke:#0B2161;}
</style>
   <path d="M 35 10 L 60 60 L 35 110 L 10 60 Z M 60 60 L 30 70 L 10 60 M 35 110 L 30 70 L 35 10" fill=#FFFFFF stroke=#000000/>
</svg>
```

ВЕРСИЯ ***Firefox 6.0***

Comment: Может явно указать что svg:hover{border:none; outline:none;} проверь

Comment: Неа, не помогло.

Comment: @Frodo Добавьте в вопрос код svg файла и css. Без этой информации остается только гадать и без кода вопрос скорее всего закроют, как - **Слишком общий**

Comment: @Alexandr_TT  вот я и пытаюсь ванговать !

Comment: @Frodo Добавить код  в окне редактирования можно нажав на иконку - **Добавление html / css/JS**   или CTRL+M

Comment: Я пишу с телефона) а код на компе и переходника нету

Comment: @Frodo это во внимание не принимается, откуда вы пишите, если нужен конкретный ответ- приложите усилия для оформления вопроса

Comment: Ну вроде всё: и код добавил, и версию браузера

Comment: Я лично не понял, в чем именно проблема... Что именно в конечном итоге хотелось бы получить автору...

Comment: На фото проблема, а мне нужна полная заливка.

Comment: @Frodo поставил плюс за вопрос и оформление

Comment: @Frodo нужна полная заливка чего? Всей подложки и пустого места под ромб до наведения? Слова можно понять по разному, пытайтесь формулировать, так, чтобы было однозначно понятно По комментарию исправлю свой код

Comment: При наведении на svg элемент заливается фон path элемента, а svg не заливается (это в Firefox) и остается что-то вроде рамки. А в IE11 при наведении на svg элемент, заливается svg элемент и никакой рамки нету. Мне конечно помогло stroke-width: 3px; Но это не решение моей проблеммы. Нужна заливка подложки (svg)

Answer (score 2):

Проблема заключается в том, что браузеры немного по разному выполняют масштабирование `svg` относительно контейнера и окна браузера.
Наиболее правильно выполняет масштабирование, как это должно быть по спецификации W3C,- `Firefox`. Хуже всего, с многочисленными ошибками масштабирует svg,- `IE`.

Раз у вас всё было наоборот,- появлялась рамка только в `FF`, значит не все условия были выполнены для правильного масштабирования.

В вашем случае это отсутствие `viewBox`, который как раз отвечает за масштабирование и адаптивность svg изображения при изменении размера окна браузера.

Я добавил `viewBox="0 0 70 120"` и обернул svg в контейнер `<div class="container">`, изменяя проценты ширины и высоты, которого, можно менять исходные размеры `svg`

```css
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%; 
background:#D5D5D5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg width="15%" height="25%" viewBox="0 0 70 120">
<style>
    path{stroke:white;}
    svg{background:#0080FF;}
    svg:hover{background:#A9A9F5;}
    path:hover{fill:#FFFF00; stroke:#0B2161;}
</style>
   <path d="M 35 10 L 60 60 L 35 110 L 10 60 Z M 60 60 L 30 70 L 10 60 M 35 110 L 30 70 L 35 10" fill=#FFFFFF stroke=#000000/>
</svg> 

</div>
```

### 2# вариант

```css
 * {margin:0; padding:0;}
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%; 
background:#D5D5D5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg width="15%" height="25%" viewBox="0 0 70 120">
<style>
    path{stroke:white;}
    svg{background:#0080FF;}
    svg:hover{background:#A9A9F5;}
    path:hover{fill:#FFFF00; stroke:#0B2161;}
</style>
   <path d="M 35 10 L 60 60 L 35 110 L 10 60 Z M 60 60 L 30 70 L 10 60 M 35 110 L 30 70 L 35 10" fill=#FFFFFF stroke=#000000/>
</svg> 

</div>
```

### #3 Вариант

```css
* {margin:0; padding:0;}
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%; 
background:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg width="15%" height="25%" viewBox="0 0 70 120" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYmin meet">
<style>
    path{stroke:white;}
     rect{fill:#0080FF;}
     rect:hover{fill:#A9A9F5;}
    path:hover{fill:#FFFF00; stroke:#0B2161;}
</style> 
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" />
   <path d="M 35 10 L 60 60 L 35 110 L 10 60 Z M 60 60 L 30 70 L 10 60 M 35 110 L 30 70 L 35 10" fill=#FFFFFF stroke=#000000/>
</svg> 

</div>
```

**Приложение svg полностью адаптивно**

Comment: К сожалению этот вариант не помог.      При наведении на svg элемент заливается фон path элемента, а svg не заливается (это в Firefox) и остается что-то вроде рамки. А в IE11 при наведении на svg элемент, заливается svg элемент и никакой рамки нету. Мне конечно помогло stroke-width: 3px; Но это не решение моей проблеммы. Нужна заливка подложки (svg)

Comment: @Frodo изменил, посмотрите и пишите дальше, если что-то не так

Comment: @Frodo Добавлен 3 вариант

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь, получилось залить, но дойдя до второго элемента я передумал, что это вообще надо, просто квадрат через path нарисую да и залью. Короче говоря, залить svg элемент можно, при помощи манипуляции с viewBox, но очень геморойно получается (очень очень очень). Пришлось отказаться от этого, но теперь другая проблема. Элемент path через css не хочет трансформироваться, только напрямую, а очень надо через css.

Comment: @Frodo благодарю за отзыв, но вдвойне было бы приятно получить плюсик за свою работу. На сайте принято, если вы поменяли свое решение после полученного ответа, на **первый вариант вопроса**, то необходимо поблагодарить автора ответа и задать новый вопрос, а здесь указать на него ссылку.. По вопросу в комментарии - патч с помощью только css не транcформируется.